# Why is this an incorrect answer for finding the Majority Element within an array on Leetcode.com and interviewbit.com

Tags: php, arrays, element

Question:

Given an array of size N, find the majority element. The majority element is the element that appears more than floor(N/2) times.
You may assume that the array is non-empty and the majority element always exist in the array.

My answer:

```
function majorityElement($a){
    
    $arr = array_count_values($a);
    $newArr = array_flip($arr);
    
    return $newArr[max($arr)];
}
```

Links to page for reference:

https://leetcode.com/problems/majority-element/

https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/majority-element/

Why is my answer incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: Because you are returning the value that occurs the most. You are not as requested returning the number that occurs in more that half the occurances

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't think this is the problem, because I submitted this answer on leetcode.com, and it was accepted.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It says "You may assume that the majority element always exists in the array" so shouldn't the value that occurs the most be the correct answer? I'm new to these tests so I'm probably missing something obvious. I'm trying to read your comment carefully word for word and understand what you are saying.

Comment: I have only tried this on interviewbit I just assumed leetcode would bring back the same result.

Comment: Just tested and also works on leetcode for me too.

Comment: The way I read the question is that you have to find the number that occurs in more than half the values of the array, so if your array is 5 occurances the number has to occur 3 times. But because they said said > floor(N/2) it would be 2 or more times. The reason they say "_You may assume that the majority element always exists_" is so you dont have to bother about checking that no such value exists and complicating your code with a  lot of validation

Comment: I also note that the question is slightly different on those 2 sites. interviewbit uses the `floor(N/s)`  and leetcode uses `N/2`

Comment: Although, if you think about it, if we can assume "_that the majority element always exist_" the whole `N/2` or `floor(N/2)` seems to be completely irrelevant and superfluous

Comment: In my experience, the people setting these interview tests were rarely as clever as they thought they were. And should you corrected something, they were as likely as not to Not employ you as they would worry you might be cleverer than they were. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only interview questions that I am exposed to are the Stack Overflow ones.  I have no idea what the designers of this task were thinking -- and it is certainly off-topic on Stack Overflow to speculate about why other developers do the things that they do.

I'd say that if I was to take this challenge, I'd strive to minimize the time complexity by implementing a conditional early return as soon as a majority number is determined.

This snippet never needs to iterate more than once over the data set.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GmLgB))

```
class Solution {
    /**
     * @param Integer[] $nums
     * @return Integer
     * @throws Exception
     */
    function majorityElement(array $nums): int
    {
        $majorityPoint = intdiv(count($nums), 2);
        foreach ($nums as $num) {
            $result[$num] = ($result[$num] ?? 0) + 1;
            if ($result[$num] > $majorityPoint) {
                return $num;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception('No majority number in data set');
    }
}
```